# What is the meaning of the discounted process defined from the interest rate process?

Tags: interest-rates

Assume a money market has interest rate process $R(t)$. In Shreve's [Stochastic Calculus for Finance II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144192311X), formula (5.2.17) on page 215 defines the discounted process as
$$
D(t) = e^{-\int_0^t R(s) ds}.
$$

Why is $D(t)$ called "discounted" process?

Does it mean that any value at time t times $D(t)$ will give its present value  at time $0$?

Comment: Note that this question is really barely on topic: I guess you're not a professional quant are you? Anyway, a quick answer was enough, but please look at the [faq] in the future.

Comment: @SRKX: I have taken a course for the first four chapters of the book by Shreve, and I am learning the rest of the book now.

Comment: I get that. But the question is trivial; you even guessed the answer inside. So I guess you can see why I say that if you were a professional quant, you wouldn't have asked it. You can accept the answer if you're OK with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, $D(t)$ is the [discount factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounting#Discount_factor) used to compute the present value of a cash flow at time $t$:

$$PV = D(t) \cdot CF_t$$

It is more convenient to write it that way when you assume stochastic interest rate because you don't have to write the integral all the time.